# Add action in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

In the show page i whant add order quantity in my session. 
This is my action

```
/**
 * @Route("/add/{id}", name="add_action")
 * @param Request $request
 * @param $id
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
 */
public function addAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $basket = $session->get('basket');

    $key = array_search($id, $basket);
    if(!$key)
    {
        $basket[$key] = $request->query->get('item');
        $session->set('basket', $basket[$key]);
    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('basket_action');
}
```

In this action i have error `Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given`. What can be done to make it work?

P.S.
part of my template

```
<form method="get" action="{{ path('add_action', {'id' : product.id}) }}">
        <select class="form-control" name="item">
            {% for i in 1..10 %}
                <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <button class="btn btn-success" >Add to basket</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The error states that your session variable $session->get('basket'); is null,   make sure that you session variable is stored properly. Also have you tried using session service $this->get('session')->get('basket'); ?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 $basket = $session->get('basket');
```

to

```
 $basket = $session->get('basket', array());
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not storing basket as an array on session correctly, I would need to see your code where stores it. You can add a check if is an array before using array_search to prevent this error